# Should we create [haskell-program-coverage] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

HPC is a utility for generating coverage reports of Haskell programs.

https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_program_coverage

The source code is here: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/packages/hpc

The tag [hpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hpc) is "high performance computing."

The tags [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) and [code-coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-coverage) already exist. In my opinion, this utility should have its own tag [haskell-program-coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-program-coverage).

*[Combining test coverage with hpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343758/combining-test-coverage-with-hpc)* is an example question.